# Release sessions not showing up in Sentry

Tags: python, sentry

I have added Sentry to my Python program like this:

```py
        sentry_sdk.init(
            "https://2de30dc7030a4a78a41fad327ba0acff@o1107570.ingest.sentry.io/6134822",
            traces_sample_rate=1.0,
            release=__version__,
            auto_session_tracking=True,
        )
        sentry_sdk.set_user(dict(id=get_user_id()))
```

This is supposed to also track user sessions, the `auto_session_tracking` would default to `True` anyway. When I take a look at the web interface, however, I see that my messages (send via `sentry_sdk.capture_message(event)`) show up, but there are no users tracked for the releases:

[image]

It refers to the documentation, but there is a gap there. This has already [been reported](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-docs/issues/3473). In that issue is stated that the feature is available, just the documentation is missing still.

Do I have to do anything special to get this tracked properly?

Answer (score 1):

The `auto_session_tracking` config currently only applies to our [WSGI middleware](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/blob/4e346acbabb1fd5592663bf9acd580835236fcf0/sentry_sdk/integrations/wsgi.py#L113) so it'll only be effective with a framework/integration that uses that WSGI middleware (Django being the obvious example).

If you wish to track a session yourself, we have a context manager that you can use as below.

```py
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.sessions import auto_session_tracking

with auto_session_tracking(session_mode="request"):
    with sentry_sdk.push_scope():
        sentry_sdk.capture_message("foobar")
```

The `session_mode` argument can be either `"request"` or `"application"` with semantics documented [here](https://develop.sentry.dev/sdk/sessions/#sdk-considerations). Adding automatic session tracking more generally to other frameworks is on our roadmap. We will also update the docs to clarify this.